# Function to make user input case insensitive

Tags: excel, case-insensitive

I have the following code

```
Private Function FiltraSexo(ByVal strTexto As String) As String

strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "M", "H")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "F", "M")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "Hombre", "H")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "Mujer", "M")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "Femenino", "M")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "Masculino", "H")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "hombre", "H")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "mujer", "M")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "femenino", "M")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "masculino", "H")

CURPFiltraSexo = UCase(strTexto)

End Function
```

This is a function that works for another function that the user can give the data or select it from a cell. If the user types any of the words in the function it will replace it with an M or H.

If the user has a typo like HOmbre instead of Hombre it won't change the value.

Is there a way to be case insensitive for what the user writes?

Comment: You can make it case insenstive by changing `strTexto` to all lower case. But another issue with your algorithm is that `Replace` will replace the found character; it does not check that the entire word matches.  So if user types in `Hom` your algorithm would return `HOH`, probably not what you want. To avoid typo's and the like, using a dropdown list to select valid entries might be safer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `Select` statement

```
Private Function FiltraSexo(ByVal strTexto As String) As String
    Dim tmp As String
    tmp = LCase$(strTexto)
    Select Case tmp
        Case Is = "femenino"
            FiltraSexo = "M"
        Case Is = "mujer"
            FiltraSexo = "M"
        Case Is = "hombre"
            FiltraSexo = "H"
        
            ''''
        
        Case Else
            MsgBox "error"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Yes this works great, thanks! Only one question is `Case is` how many characters does it requires? as if i put `Case is = "h", it goes directly to `Case Else`

Comment: check this [tutorial](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-select-case/)

Comment: Thanks the tutorial was very helpful, now all works great!